# Mistaken for bad mouthing

Tags: communication

I was mistaken for bad mouthing a colleague by my boss. I admit I am a poor communicator, however I was merely stating the problems at that point. How can I set this right, what are the manners to positively approach such a situation. I never intended to hurt anyone. What ways can I develop my communication mannerism at workplace.

Comment: There are literally books written on this exact question(What ways can I develop my communication in the workplace).  The question as it stands is far to broad.  However if you were to focus the question more perhaps explaining what you did, how it was intended, how it was received and ask how you could have made it more clear this would be ontopic

Comment: As Chad said, there are entire books about this sort of thing.  One of the classics is Dale Carnegie's [How to Win Friends & Influence People](http://www.amazon.com/How-Win-Friends-Influence-People/dp/0671027034/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1446215653&sr=8-1&keywords=dale+carnegie+how+to+win+friends+and+influence+people). Some people consider it hokie and old-fashioned, but it's very good and still applicable. Some of the same people who've criticized it when it was recommended have come back to say it's good once they've actually read it ... including me.

Answer (score 1):

Good communication and transparency are keys here. I would recommend you have a private conversation with your boss when both parties are calm. Explain to him / her what your intentions were in your communication and you apologize if what you said were interpreted as a personal attack. Saying something similar to the following should work:

> I apologize if what I said earlier was misconstrued as a personal attack. It was not my intention to hurt anyone, but I merely offering feedback to my peer's work. (I assume you were by "Stating the problems."

I also highly suggest you f**ollow up with an email to your manager to document this instance** in order to protect yourself if your manager were to use this point against you, for example, in your periodic evaluations.

I work in audit, a job that calls for precise communication, and one in which feedback is not always welcome. Documenting one's communication in writing minimizes misunderstanding from both sides, and helps with objectivity when giving feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep it simple. Simple misunderstandings should stay simple, making it more complex will only make things more difficult. If you create a whole story and issue about it, than that might be interpretted as if you did mean it and you're just trying to save your *ss, without actually meaning the explanation.

> Hi Collegae,
>   About the other day, when we were discussing X and Y I mentioned "*Sentence that got misunderstood*", and thinking back about it, I'm afraid it might've sounded more negative and/or personal than intended.
>
> To be sure, while I think *Topic_It_Was_About* has room for improvement, I didn't mean it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a different approach to giving advice here. What do you do when you screw up at the work place? Move along. I think by further explaining your miscommunication you're opening the door to have to further explain what you explained.

> I admit I am a poor communicator, however I was merely stating the problems at that point.

It sounds like you already told the person you were a poor communicator and apologized. I would just leave it at that for now unless the issue is brought up again. At that point, bring in your boss, and offended person(s) and explaining it bluntly and to the point. Until then I think the best case is to leave it alone.

Answer (score -1):

I would do nothing about this instance. But keep it in mind and avoid doing it in future. Probably the other party is not taking it that seriously and it will all blow over. Apologising when you were in the right (as you say) is non productive. You may have upset someone, who may well have needed to be straightened out.

I doubt very much your boss would appreciate having to get more involved over something trivial. He/she has already bought it to your attention, a professional is expected to learn the first time and that's the end of the matter.

Comment: This doesnt even attempt to give guidance to the question

Answer (score -6):

Regardless of how you communicate  in the workplace there is always a possibility that someone will misunderstand you and take offence because of the conceits, biases and  prejudices they have. You have control over only your communication and not over the stuff inside other people's minds.

The best approach is never to talk to your boss about the issues you have with colleagues as most bosses tend to be quite out of touch with reality and simply expect the team to magically get along together. So if you talk to a boss about the problems with a colleague then you are creating cracks in your boss's fantasy and so s/he will decide it is you who is badmouthing.

Avoid interaction with the problem colleague as far as possible. If you are both asked to work on a task together then divide up the task into subtasks so that you can do your subtasks with minimal interaction with the  problem colleague. Do not help your problem colleague; find a good pretext to not do that. Remember team morale, team spirit, success of project etc. are entirely your boss's problem not yours, especially with a boss who has this kind of attitude.

When your communication is entirely within the narrow boundaries of what a boss expects  communication will not be a problem for you.

Comment: "The best approach is never to talk to your boss about the issues you have with colleagues as most bosses tend to be quite out of touch with reality and simply expect the team to magically get along together." Why the cynicism?

Comment: I'm more concerned about the "Do not help the problem colleague" bit - if you won't work with a certain colleague, and you won't talk to your manager about it so they can address any problems, you're being part of the problem. And if you're expecting the boss to manage team morale, team spirit etc. then you have to talk to them and give them the information to do that.

Comment: The OP spoke bluntly to a colleague, perhaps too bluntly, when pointing out a flaw, and suddenly this is a "problem colleague" that the OP should avoid interacting with, all while saying nothing to the boss? This is a recipe for being fired. **OP, do not follow this advice.** I speak as a manager. If your manager thinks you misspoke to your colleague, following this advice would cement that impression and make you the problem